# Como puedo hacer que los options de un datalist tengan por separado un href al clickearlo

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, options, datalist

Quiero hacer que cada un `<option>` de un `datalist` tenga en conjunto una URL que al darle click a ese `option` te mande a esa pagina. Este es mi código.

```javascript
const LinkPage = page => window.open(`/page-${page}`);

$(document).ready(()=>{
   let reflejadorTituloPagina = $(".txtp1");
   reflejadorTituloPagina.text(`${document.title}`);
   
   const animes_List = ["Kimetsu No Yaiba", "Shingeki No Kyojin", "Bungous Stray Dogs", "Peach Boy"];
   let dataList_Contenedor = document.querySelector(".container-options-animes");
   dataList_Contenedor.innerHTML = "";

   for (let i = 0; i < animes_List.length; i++) {
       let animesOptions = animes_List[i];
       dataList_Contenedor.innerHTML +=`<option>
           <button arial-label="${animesOptions} button" onclick="LinkPage('${String.prototype.trim(animesOptions)}')">
               ${animesOptions}
           </button>
       </option>
       `
   }
})
```

Ayuda :'v

Comment: Tengo una duda, ¿andas usando alguna librería para ese ```datalist```? porque si es puro HTML, no podrás redireccionar al usuario cuando de click en alguna ```option```

Comment: No estoy usando ninguna librería, pero estoy usando jQuery para hacer mi trabajo en JS. No uso bootstrap en este momento y sí es puro HTML.

Comment: Hola Yukoso, al parecer lo que estas intentando hacer es un buscador en tiempo real?

Comment: Si, es lo que trato hacer pero no logro dar con mi objetivo